# How to catch "Enter" command a in Textarea element in server-side?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm building a app that I need to catch the text of textarea with all lines separated. That is, if the user typed in textarea and press "Enter" to do a new line. Is there a way I can get the text from textarea and know the places where the user lines separated by "Enter"?

From my tests, in Internet Explorer I can get using `Environment.NewLine`:

```
string someString = TextArea1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```

But using Firefox or Chrome did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
string someString = TextArea1.Text.Replace( Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(13)) + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(10)), "<br />")
```

### edit

thats the final solution after trying some others.

please look at history of this question for more solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran my own test, and this worked for me.

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n","<br />");
```

Something else is wrong if it is not for you.

Comment: It does for me.  And it has nothing to do with your browser, the code is being replaced server-side.

Comment: Hmmm I don't think so. But the code sent to the server seems different depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had problems with "\r\n" in the past. However, this has always seemed to work for me:

```
string someString = TextArea1.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

I also like to be anal about making sure nothing gets missed so I often do:

```
string someString = TextArea1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

But the first one should work fine.

Good Luck!